# unregister broadcast calls before onReceive() listens

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-contentprovider

I am working on an android sms application.The following code I used to send SMS.

```
 public void sendsms(){
 sendBroadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (getResultCode()) {

                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    System.out.println("hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee8888888888888888");
                    System.out.println("1111111111111111111111111111111111");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("address", phoneNumber);
                    values.put("body", message);
                    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
                    afterSend();
                    break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println("222222222222222222222222222");
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println("333333333333333333333333333333333");
                    ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();

                    values1.put("address", phoneNumber);
                    values1.put("body", message);
                    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/queued"), values1);
                    afterSend();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    System.out.println("44444444444444444444444444");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    System.out.println("4444444444444444444444444444444444");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;



                default:
                    break;
            }               
        }
    };     

    registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver , new IntentFilter(SENT));


    //--- when the SMS hasbeen delivered---

    deliveryBroadcastReciever=new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    System.out.println("okkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    System.out.println("cancellllllllllllllllllll");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }               
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReciever, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));


    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);


    unregisterReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver);
    unregisterReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReciever);
}
```

Now my problem is if I send an sms, The broadcast  unregistered before the `sentsms` reaches the `onreceive()`.So onReceive() switch block() is unreachable for most of the cases. If I don't write the unregister call then at the time of sending second sms.The `onreceive()` will listen both first and second sms .

So please help to solve this issue by make unregister call after complete `onreceive()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue partially.
I remove the unregister(broadcast) from end of the sms method and put it in onreceive() method.So the unregister() will happen after reach onreceive() only.My working code is pasted below.

```
 public void sendsms(){
 sendBroadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (getResultCode()) {

                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    System.out.println("hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee8888888888888888");
                    System.out.println("1111111111111111111111111111111111");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("address", phoneNumber);
                    values.put("body", message);
                    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
                    afterSend();
                    break;

                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println("222222222222222222222222222");
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println("333333333333333333333333333333333");
                    ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();

                    values1.put("address", phoneNumber);
                    values1.put("body", message);
                    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/queued"), values1);
                    afterSend();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    System.out.println("44444444444444444444444444");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    System.out.println("4444444444444444444444444444444444");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;



                default:
                    break;
            }
                            context.unregister(this);               
        }
    };     

    registerReceiver(sendBroadcastReceiver , new IntentFilter(SENT));


    //--- when the SMS hasbeen delivered---

    deliveryBroadcastReciever=new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    System.out.println("okkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    System.out.println("cancellllllllllllllllllll");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }   
            context.unregister(this)            
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(deliveryBroadcastReciever, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));


    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);



}
```

Now my code is working well for sendBroadcastReceiver.

But in the case of deliveryBroadcastReciever the the receiver() never listen any delivery.So deliveryBroadcastReciever is registering for every send sms.

So i tried with onstop()

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
             unregister(deliveryBroadcastReceiver);
             }
```

But the onStop() is unregistering last registerd deliveryBroadcastReceiver object only.If i send sms twice, there will be two deliveryBroadcastReceiver objects and onstop() will unregistering last object only. Please help me friends.

Comment: Use onResume and onPause for registering and unregistering.

Comment: @PoweRoy..Can you please explain..How Can i register for every sms?